# how to bold words within a paragraph in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I am a beginner in web programming and have some very simple questions.

I'm trying to bold several words in one paragraph but I don't know how to do that using HTML/CSS. I've figured out how to bold entire paragraphs, but not individual words yet. How can I bold one word, like "bold" in my example?

This bolds an entire paragraph:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p.n1
{
    font:15px bold 30px Georgia,serif;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="n1">I am in bold. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
<p><strong>This is in bold.</strong> This is not.</p>
```

You might find [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML) to be a very handy and reliable reference.

Comment: Beat me to it, nice, here's the URL for HTML 4.01 specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1 and from the HTML 5.0 draft specification: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-strong-element

Comment: `strong` doesn't necessarily imply boldness, but that the text within is of higher relative importance. `b` is the correct tag to use if you simply wish to change the presentational style, or alternatively use a `span` element with an appropriately styled class. The same is true of `em` for emphasis and `i`.

Comment: While b and strong are separate elements, strictly stylistic information (such as b) belongs in the stylesheet. However, I concede your point. What I probably should have pointed him to was the use of a nested span, with an id, and the use of a style to bold it. But that's a bit on the purist side, and I took the most direct route to solving the problem.

Answer (score 17):

I know this question is old but I ran across it and I know other people might have the same problem. All these answers are okay but do not give proper detail or actual TRUE advice.

When wanting to style a specific section of a paragraph use the span tag.

```
<p><span style="font-weight:900">Andy Warhol</span> (August 6, 1928 - February 22, 1987) 

was an American artist who was a leading figure in the visual art movement known as pop 

art.</p>
```

**Andy Warhol** (August 6, 1928 - February 22, 1987) was an American artist who was a leading figure in the visual art movement known as pop art.

As the code shows, the span tag styles on the specified words: "Andy Warhol". You can further style a word using any CSS font styling codes.

```
{font-weight; font-size; text-decoration; font-family; margin; color}, etc.
```

Any of these and more can be used to style a word, group of words, or even specified paragraphs without having to add a class to the CSS Style Sheet Doc. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 8):

```
<p><b> BOLD TEXT </b> not in bold </p>;
```

Include the text you want to be in bold between `<b>...</b>`

Answer (score 5):

if you want to just "bold", [Mike Hofer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9058449/2188245) is mostly correct.

but notice that the  tag bolds its contents by default, but you can change this behavior using css, example:

```
p strong {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Now your "bold" is italic :)

So, try to use tags by its meaning, not by its default style.

Comment: quick note: the way answers are sorted could change over time (or depending on how a particular user sorts them), so instead of "above answer", you should mention the answerer's name and/or include a link to the answer itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
p.boldpara {font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="boldpara">Stack overflow is good site for developers. I really like this site </p>

</body>

</html>
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com

Comment: *Stack overflow is best site for developers.

Answer (score 1):

Although your answer has many solutions I think this is a great way to save lines of code. Try using spans which is great for situations like yours.

1. Create a class for making any item bold. So for paragraph text it would be

> ```
> span.bold(This name can be anything do not include parenthesis) {
>    font-weight: bold;
> }
> ```

1. In your html you can access that class like by using the span tags and adding a class of bold or whatever name you have chosen

Answer (score 1):

Add `<b>` tag

```
<p> <b> I am in Bold </b></p>
```

For more text formatting tags  [click here](http://webdesigningbydkc.blogspot.com/2015/07/html-text-formatting.html)