# How do i use 1 <span> tag to bold multiple words? for example in the text below

Tags: html, css

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIWXU.png)
How do I use 1  tag to bold multiple words? for example in the text below Bold Mon-Fri but not the times when I put multiple  tags I get a duplicate id Day error, thank you for the help!
Im looking for something more of the line of, in my code i have Mon 8AM-8PM Tue 8AM-8PM Wed8AM-8PM Thu8AM-8PM Fri8AM-8PM, is there a way i could select only the abbreviations for the days of the week and bold them? when i try to use multiple  tags i get an ID Day Duplicate error!

Comment: Could you post the question body, posting image instead of text format reduceses probability of answer significantly.

Comment: Use a `class` instead of `id` to mark the days for bolding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well do not use `id` for the spans. Use other attributes like `class` or `data`

```css
.day {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="day">Mon</span> 8AM-8PM <span class="day">Tue</span> 8AM-8PM <span class="day">Wed</span> 8AM-8PM <span class="day">Thu</span> 8AM-8PM <span class="day">Fri</span> 8AM-8PM
```

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain how you get these dates, maybe we can find another solution. For what you have explained, this would be a working solution

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem with the errors, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something similar to that mentioned in below thread

[how to bold words within a paragraph in HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058425/how-to-bold-words-within-a-paragraph-in-html-css)

Or using span element, you may do something similar to below code

```
<p>Showing how to  <span style="font-weight:bold;">bold </span>any word 
in a given sentence...</p>
<p style="font-weight:bold;">...and see how multiple words are in bold. 
</p>
```

or you can use below code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<p id="given">Mon 8AM-8PM Tue 8AM-8PM Wed8AM-8PM Thu8AM-8PM Fri8AM-8PM. 
</p> 
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try to see it </button> 
<script> function myFunction() { 
document.getElementById("given").innerHTML= 
document.getElementById("given").innerHTML.replace(/[a-zA-Z]{3}/g, 
function(str) {return '<b>'+str+'</b>'}) } 
</script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Im looking for something more of the line of, in my code i have Mon 8AM-8PM Tue 8AM-8PM Wed8AM-8PM Thu8AM-8PM Fri8AM-8PM, is there a way i could select only the abbreviations for the days of the week and bold them? when i try to use multiple <span id="day"> tags i get an ID Day Duplicate error!

Comment: Using same id value will obviously throw you such Duplicate error. What you can do is      i. Add a regex to extract the desired days of the week from the given string.    ii. Dynamically add span element with bold css ONLY for those which matches the regex.

Comment: Thank you! is there any chance you could give me an example of said regrex to extract the days? Im not familiar with how exactly to do that, i appreciate it very much!

Comment: Haven't tried it but you could you try something like :  [a-zA-Z]{3}    The idea here is to extract the day of the week which is believed to be only three alphabets in given string.

Comment: You may try below code:    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p id="given">Mon 8AM-8PM Tue 8AM-8PM Wed8AM-8PM Thu8AM-8PM 
    Fri8AM-8PM.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try to see it </button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
   
    document.getElementById("given").innerHTML=     
    document.getElementById("given").innerHTML.replace(/[a-zA-Z]{3}/g, 
    function(str) {return '<b>'+str+'</b>'})
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Please mark the answer as right if this is what you were trying to achieve. I have added the code snippet for you in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using span element you can try out it in another way

```html
<strong>Mon</strong> 8AM-8PM <strong>Tue</strong> 8AM-8PM <strong>Wed</strong> 8AM-8PM <strong>Thu</strong> 8AM-8PM <strong>Fri</strong> 8AM-8PM
```