# How do I style this text to be bold?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to style this text to be bold in Shopify?

```
 <center> <font color="black">Free Shipping & Returns</font> <center>
```

I also want it to adapt the same typography but not sure how to do that. Currently I am in the product-template.liquid file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to bold words within a paragraph in HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058425/how-to-bold-words-within-a-paragraph-in-html-css)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make text bold in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082353/how-do-i-make-text-bold-in-html)

Comment: Yes it does thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS to achieve this using the `font-weight` property.

```html
<center style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">
    Free Shipping & Returns
<center>
```

To do this with just raw HTML:

```html
<center>
    <strong>Free Shipping & Returns</strong>
</center>
```

Comment: The HTML version worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**1. You can bold your text with 2 ways**

### Way - 1

```html
<center> <font color="black;"><b>Free Shipping & Returns</b></font> <center>
```

### Way - 2

```html
<center> <font color="black;"><strong>Free Shipping & Returns</strong></font> <center>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do  `<center> <font color="black; font-weight: bold">Free Shipping & Returns</font> <center>` that should work

Answer (score 2):

`<center><b>Free Shipping & Returns</b><center>`

Answer (score 1):

There are **3 ways** to achieve your desired result

### First Option

```
<center> <font color="black" style="font-weight: bold;"> <center>
```

### Second Option

```
<center> <font color="black"><b>Free Shipping & Returns</b></font> <center>
```

### Third Option

```
<center> <font color="black"><strong>Free Shipping & Returns</strong></font> <center>
```

Comment: The first option needs a slight adjustment. (`<font color="black" style="font-weight: bold;">`)

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight: bold;
```

or

```
<b></b>
```